# how to click multiple buttons in a row with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, click, intervals

is it possible to create script that click multiple buttons in a row with x time interval between clicks ?

for example when first button is clicked after x time second is clicked and etc. 
(using Javascript).

```
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
 for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
       setInterval(function() 
    {inputs[i].click() },1000  
  }
```

Comment: Please post the codes that you've tried.

Comment: Sure it's most likely possible. Show us what you have tried and where you ran into problems

Answer (score 2):

**use this code**

```js
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("button")
var timeInterval = 5000 // x time in miliseconds

function pressButton(iteration=0){
  
    setTimeout(function(){

      allButtons[iteration].click();
      pressButton(iteration++);

    }, timeInterval)
    
}

pressButton();
```

```html
<div id="parent">

<button class="button" type="submit" > </button>
<button class="button" type="submit" > </button>
<button class="button" type="submit" > </button>
<button class="button" type="submit" > </button>
<button class="button" type="submit" > </button>

</div>
```

More can be helped if you paste your code

Comment: You'll need to move your increment to before the iteration variable. (e.g. `pressButton(++iteration)`)

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var clickcallback = function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      let id = "button" + i;
      document.getElementById(id).click();
    }, 1000);   // one second
    if(i <= 3) {
        clickcallback(i+1);
    }
  };
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="button1" onClick="alert('click button1');">Button 1</button>
  <button id="button2" onClick="alert('click button2');">Button 2</button>
  <button id="button3" onClick="alert('click button3');">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Here the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/frasim/730xmhfv/8/